# Django logout infinite loop?

Tags: django

Why is this running into an infinite loop, and 'TESTING' never gets printed? It seems like the `logout` function is causing the page to redirect to itself, but the [documentation suggests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout) that you can put your own redirect *after* calling that function.

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    print 'TESTING'
    messages.success(request, 'Logged out.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['next'] or reverse('home'))
```

Is there another way to log the user out, if this logout function has some hidden redirect functionality?

---

Just took a peek at the source code, nothing suspicious there:

```
def logout(request):
    """
    Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
    session data.
    """
    request.session.flush()
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

I really can't imagine what's causing this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have written:

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
```

which means You call the **view itself** - not the `logout` function.

You can fix this by writing:

```
from django.contrib import auth
# ...
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    # ...
```

In addition You do not have to write own logout view - it is given already by default as [django.contrib.auth.views.logout](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout).

Comment: Oh... hahahaha... I'm an idiot >.< Thanks. I even had them lined up, one perfectly below the other, and it never occured to me.

Comment: Just wanted to mention--I always name my views with an _page at the end if they are used to display content. EG: Instead of logout, I'd write logout_page. It makes working with the Django APIs much, much easier.

Comment: Mark: Don't worry. Almost everybody I know had that incident when they were starting in Django.

Comment: Yeahh.... I find Python to be a curious language that way. I always have to decide how much namespace I want to include... and this time it bit me :p